# WPF/MVVM: SelectedIndex Binding Property not updating when Combobox Selection Changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I've got a very similar question to [Jinesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130850/selection-changed-event-of-combobox-in-wpf-mvvm). I need to get **the value of** the SelectedIndex (or SelectedItem or SelectedValue) of a combo box in to my ViewModel code (i.e., when a user selects an item in the combo box, I need that index (or item or value) to update a property in the ViewModel code). I've followed the suggestions in [Sheridan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21130850/selection-changed-event-of-combobox-in-wpf-mvvm) and [Felix C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357763/wpf-selectedindex-commandparameter) but my property is not getting updated when the selected item changes. I'm trying to get the newly selected index value as part of my "Update" button code.

View:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboMonth"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MonthsList, Mode=OneTime}"
          DisplayMemberPath="month"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding MonthIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<Button Name="btnUpdate"
        Content="Update"
        Command="{Binding processUpdateButton}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Month> MonthsList { get; set; }
private int _monthIndex;

public int MonthIndex
{
    get
    {                
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        _monthIndex = today.Month - 1;
        return _monthIndex;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_monthIndex != value)
        {
            _monthIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MonthIndex");
        }
    }
} 

public ICommand processUpdateButton
{
    get
    {
        if (_setUpdateButton == null)
        {
            _setUpdateButton = new RelayCommand(param => validateOdometer());
        }
            return _setUpdateButton;
        }            
    }

public void validateOdometer()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Validating odometer...");
    Console.WriteLine("Month Index: " + (_monthIndex));        
}
```

When my page first renders, I have the combo box defaulting to index 5 (06-June) and the property in question, _monthIndex, reflects 5. When I select a new month in the combo box (e.g., October) then click my update button (btnUpdate), _monthIndex should reflect 9 but it still reflects 5. Why? Appreciate any/all help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property getter ignores the previously set value and *always* returns the index of the current month.

The declaration should look like this:

```
private int monthIndex = DateTime.Today.Month - 1;

public int MonthIndex
{
    get { return monthIndex; }
    set
    {
        if (monthIndex != value)
        {
            monthIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MonthIndex");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow on Q. I need to do the same thing with a dayIndex var (for my Day combo box) but dayIndex is calculated - it's not a declaration as monthIndex is above. Each calendar day can have 0 or more events.  e.g., if today (6/30) had three events, such events would be stored as 30, 30.1, and 30.2 (in ObservableCollection<Day>), and there is a corresponding index for each event. I currently have a method working that returns the desired index, sets it in my XAML (SelectedIndex="{Binding DayIndex}") and correctly displays Day.Event. How do I handle the declaration for dayIndex? Thanks.

Comment: Please do not ask follow-up questions in comments. Post a new question instead.